# X path and CSS selector for a specific table change for each page

Tags: html, r, selenium, xpath

I am new to HTML, I am currently working on a project using RSelenium to scrape data from html tables. I was able to use this code:

```
for(i in 1:50){
 remDR$navigate(URLs[i])
  CPSHList[[i]] <- remDR$getPageSource()[[1]] %>%
   read_html()%>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id=\"dcCSScontentContainer\"]/div/table[5])")%>%
    html_table()%>%
    data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that there are multiple tables on this page and between pages some tables are present, while others are not. Therefore, the Xpath for the specific table that I want changes for each page depending on the presence of other tables. After doing some initial research, I thought that I could perhaps change the Xpath depending on if the table contains a specific cell based on the td tag. Here is the table:

```
<table class="dcCSStableLight" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" 
 bordercolor="#ececd7">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="dark" align="left" colspan="8" bgcolor="#B0C4DE"><b>Current 
     Prison Sentence History:</b>
     </td>
   </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#B0C4DE">
    <th><b>Offense Date</b>
      </th> 
    <th><b>Offense</b>
      </th>
    <th><b>Sentence Date</b>
      </th>
    <th><b>County</b>
      </th>
    <th><b>Case No.</b>
      </th>
    <th><b>Prison Sentence Length</b>
      </th>
  </tr>
 <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <td>06/14/2015</td><td>BURG/DWELL/OCCUP.CONVEY</td>
  <td>08/04/2016</td><td>ST. JOHNS</td><td>1501553</td>
  <td nowrap="">5Y 0M 0D </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have come up with this:

```
"//div/table[contains(td, \"Current Prison Sentence History:\"]"
```

However, it is returning an Invalid Expression error in R:

```
"Invalid expression [1207]xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your xpath expression - "//div/table[contains(td, \"Current Prison Sentence History:\"]" needs to have the contains method closed, i.e. "//div/table[contains(td, \"Current Prison Sentence History:\")]"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `R`, but you are using `css` for `xPath`, what is wrong. Replace:

```
html_nodes(css = "//*[@id=\"dcCSScontentContainer\"]/div/table[5])")%>%
```

with:

```
html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id=\"dcCSScontentContainer\"]/div/table[5])")%>%
```

Also your `xPath` can be rewritten like this:

instead of:

```
//div/table[contains(td, \"Current Prison Sentence History:\")]
```

this:

```
//table[contains(b, 'Current Prison Sentence History:')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the XPath as below

```
//table//td[contains(text(),'Current Prison Sentence History:')]
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using your xpath to refine mine. I came up with this "//*[@id='dcCSScontentContainer']/div/table/tbody/tr/td/b[contains(text(),'Current')]/ancestor::table", while it highlights the table I want in Chrome developer tools- my list in R is still empty.